# Laravel: 500 server error but no error logs?

Tags: php, laravel

I have experienced a 500 server error via Laravel, and no error is being written to the log file. I've verified permissions are OK, and that Laravel can write to the log file. I am unsure what other options I have here.

I have chased the error down to this class, the commented out lines are the lines that are causing the error.

```
class CollectionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            // 'member_count' => $this->items()->count(),
            // 'member_count_today' => $this->items()->whereDate('collection_entries.created_at', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->count(),
            // 'member_images' => $this->items->take(10)->pluck('data.picture'),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

The error is rather sporadic, and doesn't always happen.

Comment: what kind of relationship is `items` ?

Comment: @ml59 It is a belongsToMany

Comment: Did you check web server error logs? (apache or etc)

Comment: @V-K yes, no error logs there either. I also checked the PHP ones.

Comment: I can suggest to you to add withCount() on the previous step where you get the entities https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Out of that temporary give full folder permissions 777 for the log and ensure that log is enabled . There is no reason why Laravel will stay silent if it has permissions to write and is set to do it.

Comment: What have you tried to debug **why** these lines cause a problem? You could start by dumping out the content if you don't want to use a higher level of error reporting

Comment: @NicoHaase that isn't the issue here, my question is how to get Laravel to report why the error happens. Saying that, I have tried but I reached a dead end. I even did a try catch, returning the exception in the catch block and Laravel still swallowed it.

Answer (score 2):

**Run this command first**

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**app/config/app.php**

```
'debug' => true, //env('APP_DEBUG'),
```

Check .env file, make sure permissions are correctly set and create the storage/logs folder(s) manually if folder is not exist.

Comment: I've tried your steps and I still don't get any details about the errors. Your second step is redundant also, `APP_DEBUG` is default to true out of the box.